# Normal distribution of a non negative random variable

Tags: normal-distribution

Why random variables like wages, stock prices (which can never be less than zero) cannot have normal distributions? Is it a limitation/assumption of random variable?
I know random variables like stock prices are positively skewed but limitation due to non negative values is not clear to me.

Reference: Introductory Econometrics: A modern approach by Woolridge (chapter 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability distribution function of normal distribution is non-zero on whole real line (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) regardless of mean and standard deviation.

This means that, for normally distributed random variable $X$, we have
$P(X<0) > 0 $.

So, since random variables like wages, stock prices can never be less than zero, they can not follow normal distribution.

Nevertheless you can have $P(X<0)$ very close to $0$, if $X$ is normally distributed with sufficiently large mean/SD ratio. Then, even random variables that can never be less than zero, can be very close to normal.

Think also of Central Limit Theorem. When you apply it to random variables that can never be less than zero, you'll see that their mean (that also can never be less than zero) is asymptotically normal.